# Can I use a multiple-client certificate in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, x509certificate, x509

I am developing an application using the ASP.NET Web API, and I am using authentication with username / password being consumed by a WPF client and I am using SSL, but for safety application I want to integrate with a client cerficate (x.509).

I'm following this example:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/159604/SSL-MakeCert-pvk2pfx-Client-Server-Certificate-Gen

The example displays setting a key on the server and the client. Currently I have several companies that consume the same service, with multiple users per company.

My question is, can I use one client key for a company, ie: multiple users accessing the same key?

If not, is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

If your service is using SSL, why do you want overhead of a certificate based security? Have you considered performance impact it may have?

If you want to go ahead with a certificate based PKI type of encryption for your services, then you can even share the same public key with all the users across all your client. Just keep the private key really private.